# How to vertically center links in a menu?

Tags: css, html, menu, alignment, center

Here's the HTML :

```
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="li_pc"><a href="#">PC</a></li>
            <li class="li_one"><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
            <li class="li_ps3"><a href="#">PS4</a></li>
            <li class="li_360"><a href="#">360</a></li>
            <li class="li_ps3"><a href="#">PS3</a></li>
            <li class="li_wiiu"><a href="#">WiiU</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and here's the CSS :

```
nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    widht: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    float: left; /* IE */
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.li_pc a:hover {
    background-color: #cc9a34;
}

.li_one a:hover {
    background-color: #149a14;
}

.li_ps4 a:hover {
    background-color: #040264;
}

.li_360 a:hover {
    background-color: #9cce04;
}

.li_ps3 a:hover {
    background-color: #0406b4;
}

.li_wiiu a:hover {
    background-color: #5c12ac;
}
```

My goal is to vertically center the text in the cells. I'm using text-align:center; to center it horizontally, but when I use vertical-align:middle; it doesn't even move a pixel. I tried a lot of different ways but it always destroys the thing and makes the design look like my face on sunday morning.

How can I center these vertically please ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you anchor links are 60px tall

```
line-height:60px
```

should do it.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/5gBNw/)

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, thanks for you quick answer !

It works perfectly.

Comment: @user2870689  You should select the Tick on the Left hand side to select this answer.

Comment: It's done :) Now I have another question. Can I post it as a comment ?

Comment: Yeah if you tag Paulie_D they may be able to answer quickly again if its only something small. If its to do with Vertical Alignment maybe http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ can help

Comment: I finally found the answer by myself. Thanks for your link btw ;)